# Associations with Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, associations, many-to-one

I'm trying make an entity with doctrine that has three associations with other entities

So an Item is associated with:

- Must be associated with One Rssfeed, which it originates from
- Can be associated with One or more Locations
- Can be associated with one or more Tags

Here is my attempt:

```
class Item{

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Rssfeed")
     */
    protected $rssfeed;

    /**
     *
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Location")
     */
    protected $locations;

    /**
     *
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag")
     */
    protected $tags;
}
```

Now

- If an Rssfeed is removed, associated items must be removed too
- If an item is removed, Rssfeeds, and Locations, and Tags attached to that item should be detached
- If a Location, or Tag is removed, the associated items should just be detached, because they are optional associations.

How should I change my code to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each association in your Item entity, add onDelete="SET NULL" to the @JoinColumn annotation. Inside your location and tag entities, find the JoinColumn annotations and add onDelete="SET NULL" for the association with "Item". Under the RssFeed entity, find each @JoinColumn annotation and add onDelete="SET NULL".
Note that you can also use Doctrine cascade operations to achieve this (i.e. cascade={"remove"}, etc; however, it will likely be significantly slower as the operating is not performed at the RDBMS level.

Comment: I tried to implement this, sounds like the right approach. Correct me if I'm wrong but you are suggesting I should have variables not only in the Item class, but also in the corresponding 3 other classes. Right? Is that a necessity?

Comment: Correct, and for what you are describing, yes.

Answer (score 1):

U have to add @JoinColumn with onDelete="CASCADE" for $rssfeed and onDelete="SET NULL" for foreign keys in Location and Tag entities.

```
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Rssfeed")
     * @JoinColumn(name="rssfeed_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $rssfeed;
```